# how to remove remove /n /t from string in iphone

Tags: objective-c

hi all iphone users...
                       hey i have an problem that i cant remove whitespace character or /n/t  in string and it retrieve from xml file. like my XMl as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alluser>
    <user>
      <username>User</username>
      <password>Pass</password>
    </user>
    <user>
       <username>Sunny</username>
       <password>Dave</password>
   </user>  
</alluser>
```

it is of when i use whole data in single line.
so please help me for this thing....

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `\n` is a newline character. If you would like to extract separate lines based on `\n` you can try the following:

```
-(NSArray *)breakStringByNewlines:(NSString *)line {
    NSArray *myArray = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    return myArray;
} // breakStringByNewlines
```

myArray will have elements that are the lines which were separated by `\n`

And to remove `\t` which is just whitespace, from a line, you could use this:

```
-(NSString *)removeWhiteSpaceFromLine:(NSString *)line {
    NSString *newline = [line stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return newline;
} // removeWhiteSpaceFromLine
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
NSString *data= [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```